# How to block Rails 4 Passenger requests from other virtual hosts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, apache2.4

I just deployed to production a Rails 4 application using Passenger on Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) and in 24 hours I found out some sites that are identical to my site.

They are using some kind of DNS forwarding because everything is working, including forms on the website.

This is my apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.com:80>
ServerName www.mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
DocumentRoot /home/deploy/mysite/public
RailsEnv production
<Directory /home/deploy/mysite/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted 
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I am not sure how to stop requests from the other domains, I have tried removing "Allow from all" and "Required all granted" but that would stop the website working even from the correct domain and these settings are required by Passenger to work.

I'm a bit stuck so if you have any suggestions I would be happy to try them.

Comment: what are you talking about? i can't follow your reasoning.

Comment: Basically using the above configuration anyone can point any domain to my server ip address and create an identical site.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all requests coming from non-existing virtual hosts are routed to your first available vhost.

In order to stop anyone for hijacking your website using DNS forward you need to have a default virtual host enabled that is loaded first (using the default name 000-default, would do the trick) and acts as a catch-all and pointed to a forbidden page or even better create a simple html page with some links to your site.